# Tyrus reconnect handler not reached on Android

Tags: android, tyrus

I managed to get [client reconnects](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.9/user-guide.html#d0e1311) working using the built-in Java 7 NIO2 client on the desktop (Windows 8.1 x64, JDK 8) with Tyrus 1.9 and prior versions as is described here: https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.9/user-guide.html#d0e1311.

On Android 4.4.4 & 5.0 (<strike>Note II, Nexus 4</strike>, Genymotion) however, nothing happens (its as if there are no handlers).  Is there some extra configuration required somewhere, or is this a limitation of the Grizzly client?

If this is a Grizzly limitation, is there a way to replicate the reconnect behavior?

**Update 05/02/15**
After some digging it turns out there was a bug in my code masked by a tiny logic error; the handler works perfectly on Android 4.4 and 5.0 on real devices.  The problem is definitely present in Genymotion on Windows 8.1 x64; apparently Genymotion on OSX works fine.